# C include file of hex constants

Tags: c, assembly, include

I need to include a file in my C program that has a bunch of hex constants in the form:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0xE8, 0x01,
0xFF, 0xF2, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE2, 0x01,
```

the above file is output from another compiler (specifically the Sigma Studio for the 1701.) and will change from time to time, so I don't want to manually massage the file each time it changes.

What you see is a snippet of the code for the 1701, and I am programming the 1701 from another u controller. This ASCII data file wants to be included in the u controller C program.

The constants begin in column 1 and there are 1024 lines each containing five 8 bit constants.

I tried to make an asm program with an include statement, and got an error message telling my only labels may begin in column 1.

Ideally, I would like to start a define block, then include the file, then end the block.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your file is called `data` and that it is formatted the way shown in the question, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char data[] = {
#include "data"
};

int main() {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

The file above includes the text from the file called `"data"` inside the curly braces, producing an array of `char`s in the `char data[]` array.

When the example above is compiled with the data from your question, it prints `20` upon running.